# Why does only Power Button wake Windows 10 Laptop from sleep?

Tags: laptop, sleep, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo Thinkpad doesn't wake from sleep anymore when I press a key, move mouse, hit touchpad or so. The only thing that works is pressing the power button.

I already wanted to make sure that these input devices are allowed to wake up the computer, but the Energy tab is missing in the Device Manager.

Comment: Have you updated the BIOS recently?

Comment: No, I didn't update my bios.

Comment: I wish my laptop did that.  Mine wakes up whenever it wants it seems.